# Predicate Logic A cup is above a book

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, predicate

Am a right or not.
The predicate logic for the following Sentences.

1. A cup is above a book.

   ```
   \x exists \y exists cup(x) and book(y) and above(x,y)
   ```
2. A cup is touching a book.

   ```
   \x exists \y exists cup(x) and book(y) and touches(x,y).
   ```
3. if x is on top of y then y supports x.

   ```
   for all x For all y on(x,y) implies support(y,x).
   ```
4. If x is above y and they are touching each other then  x is on top of y.

   ```
   for all x for all y above(x,y) and touches(x,y)  implies on(x,y).
   ```

Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

All your formulae seem reasonable representations to me.

I would add extra brackets around `above(x,y) and touches(x,y)` to ensure that both together form the antecedent of the implication. Otherwise it could be incorrectly interpretted as `above(x,y) and (touches(x,y) implies on(x,y))`